# Printing Java object to Javascript file

Tags: javascript, java, web-applications

I need to generate a Javascript file from an MVC application containing some variables needed by the Javascript (Angular-based) framework.

The controller will produce output such as

```
var currentUser = {userId: "jdoe", firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe"};
var somethingElse = [];
```

Before you ask if it's possible to retrieve that information from an AJAX call, let me say that, for now, it's not possible.

I would like to ask if there is a simple, elegant and robust way to marshal a generic Java object to Javascript notation.

So far I have tried leveraging JSON, with ugly-to-read and not robust result

```
printWriter.println(MessageFormat.format("var currentUser = JSON.parse(''{0}'');", objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user)));
```

To note:

1. JSON syntax quotes attribute names, while Javascript doesn't. JSON and Javascript are similar but different. So I need to parse JSON and not write entire JSON
2. JSON allows single quotes `'` but with such a syntax Javascript will cut the string, so I need to escape single quotes if any
3. After I escaped quotes, I don't know other possible pitfalls

So I would like to ask if there is a simpler way to marshal such an object into Javascript in a more robust but smart way.

Not using AJAX is a requirement at the moment. When it will be possible to perform a "massive" AJAX call that retrieves all needed variables at once in a single call, that will be the permanent solution.

Comment: You could simply marshal the object to JSON, and then escape all single quotes (with a backslash \\) before outputting it from your back end. At that point, simply calling JSON.parse on it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself that Jackson is capable of removing double quotes from the output JSON

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(Feature.QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES, false);
pw.println(MessageFormat.format("var currentUserInfo = {0};", objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user)));
```

From the [docs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator.Feature.html#QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES)

> QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES
>
> public static final JsonGenerator.Feature QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES
>
> Feature that determines whether JSON Object field names are quoted using double-quotes, as specified by JSON specification or not. Ability to disable quoting was added to support use cases where they are not usually expected, which most commonly occurs when used straight from Javascript.
>
> Feature is enabled by default (since it is required by JSON specification).

This will produce an output that is definitely **not** a valid JSON, however as stated in the question I am not interested in JSON.

In this case, escaping single quotes is theoretically not needed.

The output matches the intended

```
var currentUserInfo = {username:"root",completeName:"Administrator",email:null,locale:"it_IT",accountExpirationDate:null,passwordExpirationDate:null,passwordChangeable:false,creationDate:null,lastLogin:null,status:null..........};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use standard libraries to do that.

You can convert a java object to a json string (for example using jackson). Then you need to use this string adding it to a piece of javascript code.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Test());

// Now use json to add it in the custom javascript code
```